# Typescript - How to convert Error Response to Error Object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to log exceptions generated in typescript to a log file (text file). I want to log information like description,message,name,number,stack. I have written Model, API Controller and logic to write the data into text file.

However I want to map Error Response generated after get, post,put operation in typescript.
I have written below Interface

```
export interface TypeScriptException {
    Description: string;
    Message: string;
    Name: string;
    Number: string;
    ErrorStack: string;
}
```

When handleError method is called after Post in below example, how do I assign values from Error Response to my TypeScriptException object?

```
post(url: string, model: any): Observable<any> {

    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(url, body, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {

    let typeScriptException: TypeScriptException;

    //What to do here

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you receive as a part of the `error`?

Comment: If error return object. you can convert using new Error(error) . I Haven't reseted this.

Comment: if you are trying to handle http errors , then you always has an best practice  to create a custom ErrorInterceptor from [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) which can be injected into  providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of error, you get an instance of type **[`HttpErrorResponse`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse)**. You can extract fields from this instance and assign it to the `typeScriptException` variable that you've defined. You will have to leverage the details that are provided in this instance and set the fields on `typeScriptException` accordingly.

Here's what an instance of `HttpErrorResponse` looks like:

[image]

Keeping all the fields it has in mind, you can assign some of them to your `typeScriptException`, something along the lines of this:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  let typeScriptException: TypeScriptException;
  let { message, name, ok, status, statusText, url } = error;
  //What to do here?
  typeScriptException = {
    Description: `${name} - ${message}`, // OR SOMETHING
    Message: message
    Name: name,
    Number: status, // OR SOMETHING
    ErrorStack: statusText // OR SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting compile error  "Type 'Response' has no property 'message' and no string index signature." and "Type 'Response' has no property 'name' and no string index signature."

Comment: My bad. Use `(error: HttpErrorResponse)` instead of `(error: Response)`

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find name 'HttpErrorResponse'`

Comment: @FiddleFreak You need to `import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use throw method to throw new Error

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs"

private handleError(res: HttpErrorResponse) {
  Observable.throw(new Error({message:res.message,code:res.status}));
}
```

or if you want to get all property of `Response`

```
private handleError(res: HttpErrorResponse) {
  Observable.throw(new Error({...res}));
}
```

Comment: what is the type of Rx?